# Using Installshield building setup.exe - not getting proper executable compressed setup

Tags: installshield

With out using Installshield IDE using ISCmdBld.exe I want to create a compressed executable setup file and I used this command..

ISCmdBld.exe -p PDC_LANG_Setup.ism  -r %1 -z "ProductCode=%2" -z "ProductName=%ProdName%" -L ISProjectDataFolder=%ProjectDir% -b %BinPath%\%1 -z LANG_RES=%1 -y "5.4.0" -e Y -c "COMP" -v > C:\log.log

its building a executable set up but it is not executable .Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you dynamically creating release/product configurations at build time?

Answer (score 0):

ReleasePackager.exe "disk_images_folder" "package_file" ["icon_file" [icon_index]]